# List of columns with the columnToggler component of incorrect names of primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Why are the column names not appearing normal in the attached image?

[image: Screenshot]

My code:

```
<p:outputPanel style="float: right;">
    <p:commandButton id="togglertabelanfcesaida" type="button" value="Colunas Visíveis" styleClass="orange-btn"/>
    <p:columnToggler datasource="tabelanfcesaida" trigger="togglertabelanfcesaida"  />
</p:outputPanel>

<p:column headerText="" toggleable="false" id="data" width="80" style="text-align: center" sortBy="#{nfcesaida.dtEmi}">
    <f:facet name="filter">
        <h:inputHidden id="filter" />
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <p:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="ui-noborder" >
            <p:outputLabel value="Data"/>
        </p:panelGrid>
        <p:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="ui-noborder" >
            <p:calendar placeholder="&#xF002;" locale="pt_BR" id="dataInicial" inputStyle="max-width: 100%; min-width: 100%;font-family: 'FontAwesome';" effect="fadeIn" title="Data Inicial" value="#{nfceSaidaBean.dataInicialPesquisaNfceSaida}" showButtonPanel="true" navigator="true">
                <p:ajax event="dateSelect" oncomplete="PF('tabelanfcesaida').filter()" update="dataInicial dataFinal :menuform:dialogoDownloadNfceSaida" listener="#{nfceSaidaBean.ajustaDataInicialDataFinalPesquisaNfceSaida()}"/>
            </p:calendar>
            <p:calendar placeholder="&#xF002;" locale="pt_BR" id="dataFinal" inputStyle="max-width: 100%; min-width: 100%;font-family: 'FontAwesome';" effect="fadeIn" title="Data Final" value="#{nfceSaidaBean.dataFinalPesquisaNfceSaida}" showButtonPanel="true" navigator="true">
                <p:ajax event="dateSelect" oncomplete="PF('tabelanfcesaida').filter()" update="dataInicial dataFinal :menuform:dialogoDownloadNfceSaida" listener="#{nfceSaidaBean.ajustaDataInicialDataFinalPesquisaNfceSaida()}"/>
            </p:calendar>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </f:facet>
    <p:outputLabel value="#{nfcesaida.dtEmi}">
        <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
    </p:outputLabel>
</p:column>
```

Comment: Please, could you clarify what exactly do you want to achieve, because I do not understand your question?

Comment: _"I have a columnToggler component, and I have a columnToggler component, but I have a columnToggler component. "_ This is indeed totally unclear. And please re-read your question. Missing things? Please edit it then...

Comment: I edited, please check if it's good!

Answer (score 0):

The `p:dataTable` does not support other things than plain text in its header facet `<f:facet name="header">` and maybe some structural components. If you want to use 'filters', put them in the `<f:facet name="filter">`

Comment: I understand, but in my facet header are some components that I set up to give me more options of tilters, for example:

Comment: <f: facet name = "header">
                <p: panelGrid columns = "1" styleClass = "ui-noborder">
                    <p: outputLabel value = "Number" />
                </ p: panelGrid>
                <p: panelGrid columns = "1" styleClass = "ui-noborder">
                    <p: inputText id = "number" placeholder = "& # xF002;" style = "max-width: 100%; min-width: 100%; font-family: 'FontAwesome'; value = "# {nfeEntryBean.numberInfoEntry}">

Comment: <p: ajax event = "keyup" delay = "1000" oncomplete = "PF ('tabelanfeentrada') filter ()" />
                    </ p: inputText>
                </ p: panelGrid>
            </ f: facet>
if I add that filter facet of the error:
javax.faces.component.UIPanel can not be cast to javax.faces.component.ValueHolder when applying PF ('tabelanfeentrada'). filter ()
Is there not a way to modify the tosting of what is displayed inside the columnToggler?

Comment: Download the source and check.. .